# По какому принципу организовать заполнение массива?

Tags: c

Подскажите направление решения задачи.

> Дано число. Требуется заполнить массив по следующему принципу: **[номер бита числа]=значению бита числа**.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не помню, какой в x86 бит 0 -- старший или младший. Для случая "бит 0 -- младший", т.е. результатом будет двоичное представление числа в обратном порядке:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int in, r[sizeof(int)*8];
int i;
scanf("%d", &in);
for(i=0; i < sizeof r/sizeof(int); i++, in >>= 1) r[i] = in & 1;
for(i=0; i < sizeof r/sizeof(int); i++) printf("%d", r[i]);
putchar('\n');
return 0;
}
```

Т.е. в цикле выделяете младший разряд `in & 1` и сдвигаете исходное число вправо.

Comment: Если нужно сохранить значение переменной in, можно в цикле сделать вычисление r[i] = (in >> i) & 1; В условиях цикла, соответственно, убрать преобразования in.

Comment: Поговорим об оптимизации? На слабых проц. (микроконтроллеры напр.) сдвиг на один разряд -- одна команда, а сдвиг на i -- несколько.

Comment: ну вот когда будем писать для микроконтроллеров, учтем Ваше замечание.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю такой код. Пусть а - то самое число, пусть оно имеет тип int.

```
int array [sizeof(a)*8];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a)*8; i++) array[i]= ((a & (1 << i )) != 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Ну значение выражений `((a & (1 << i )) != 0 ) ? 1 : 0` и `(a & (1 << i )) != 0` в языке C одинаково. И, думаю, нормальный компилятор и код сделает одинаковый :)

Comment: Я об этом думал. Решил подстраховаться. Но Ваше решение мне больше понравилось. Браво.